# Hide HTML element with CSS if it has specific text inside it?

Tags: html, css, stylish

It's hard to manipulate websites if they don't have own class for each element.

For example, how could I hide the second element from this code below?

```
<p>
    <p>te</p>
    <p>st</p>
    <p>ing</p>
</p>
```

The text never changes inside the element.

I'm using Stylish with Firefox to edit the CSS/HTML for websites.

Comment: Under what conditions should it be hidden? I'm assuming you're looking to hide it programmatically

Comment: It should be hidden if the HTML element has "st" text inside it, and its the second element there. I dont know any better way to tell which element to hide, unless CSS has a feature to point at n'th element somehow?

Comment: CSS does indeed have such a feature: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a way of using logic (identifying a value in a tag and doing something particular) using just CSS and HTML, you'd need Javascript or some such for this. But if you're looking to hide the second p element in the text block you can do this using the nth-of-type CSS selector:

Wrap your p tags in a div and give the div a class.

```
<div class="HideChild">
    <p>te</p>
    <p>st</p>
    <p>ing</p>
</div>
```

Then in your css create a selector like this:

```
.HideChild p:nth-of-type(2)
{
display: none;
}
```

Wrapping the p tags in a div and using a class means you can reuse this function for multiple text blocks on your page. If you want to change which line is hidden change the number after nth-child, and if you want the page to show a gap where the line should be replace `display: none` with `visibility: hidden`.

Comment: Seems to work, but it doesnt count which type of element it is, lets say there are bunch of links inside the class HideChild, and some <p> tags that i want to hide. then when the amount of links changes, the nth-child function doesnt know which element to hide anymore.

Comment: Another option is to iterate through them and use jquery's `$(this).contains("");`

Comment: Good point @Rookie, updated my answer to use the nth-of-type selector instead

Comment: Works flawlessly now! Where do you find all these features of CSS? Is there any site with list of all CSS commands and i could learn them one by one?

Comment: @nerdwaller, is it possible to use JS with Stylish?

Comment: @Rookie; http://www.w3schools.com/ Will teach you everything you need to know, and has reference pages for everything too. It covers HTML, CSS, JavaScript, SQL, PHP... It's how I learned anyway :D

Comment: @CLockeWork, what are these magics such as "nth-of-type" called in there? I cant seem to find a page with those listed.

Comment: @Rookie, these are CSS Selectors http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp (and they can revolutionize the way you build your sites :D)

Comment: @rookie - Sorry to say, I've never used stylish. I tend to favor userscripts for an application like that.

Comment: @nerdwaller, application like what? its not like every website has an user-script application.

Comment: @rookie - to hide a  specific element on a given page, or fix how a specific page looks.

Comment: @nerdwaller, how can i use those userscripts? I want to do some more stuff to the HTML which i cannot do with CSS.

Comment: @Rookie - Take a look at the [Greasemonkey Wiki](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Main_Page), you should be able to find whatever you need there.  Also, you can look at source of userscripts on [Userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org).  The header is the required piece, beyond that - do whatever you need.